# JPA QL for selecting non-owning side of ManytoMany relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a ManytoMany relationship between A and B, where A is the owning side. 
I define the ManyToMany in class A:

```
@ManyToMany(....)
private Set<B> bs
```

But I don't want to expose set in B, so no @ManyToMany attribute defined in B (e.g Set as). 
It stems a problem when I want to select all B entity which an A instance is mapped to using JPA QL. I can not do:

```
"SELECT b FROM B b JOIN b.as A WHERE A.id = :id"
```

I could have set fetch = Fetch.EAGER in the @ManyToMany properties and use A.getBs() to get related B. But I prefer not to use Fetch.EAGER.
Any suggestion? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no @ManyToMany attribute defined in B (e.g Set as)

<sub>(I had to correct myself, because it seems omitting `Set<A> as` from `B` altogether won't raise an exception.)</sub>

If you only want to hide the `Set<A> as` in `B`, then you can declare it as `private` and use a bi-directional mapping (using the `mappedBy` property on the *non-owning* side of the relation). In this case the following query runs successfully:

```java
EntityManager em = ...
String sql = "SELECT b FROM B b JOIN b.as a WHERE a.id = :id";
TypedQuery<B> tq = em.createQuery(sql, B.class);
tq.setParameter("id", 100);
for (B b : tq.getResultList())
  System.out.println(b);
```

<sub>(The example snippets are all based on the tables, data and entities found in the lower sections of the answer.)</sub>

It prints:

```
B{id=333, data=b}
B{id=999, data=bbb}
```

This JPQL query is the mapping of the following native SQL query:

```sql
SELECT b.id, b.data 
FROM a, b, a_has_b 
WHERE a.id = a_has_b.a_id 
AND b.id = a_has_b.b_id 
AND a_id = 100;
```

You basically want a uni-directional relation (by omitting the `mappedBy` from `B`—down below—or droppping `Set<A> as`). This way, however, you won't be able to execute a query like you've described. Just no way it'll work.

The persistence provider will bark at you if there is no `Set<A> as` in `B` (*property could not be resolved*—in case of Hibernate). If you only omit the `mappedBy` from the non-owning side, then the persistence provider won't know where is the *other* side of *that* relation. Either you use the `mappedBy` or create an *inverse* `@JoinTable` annotation in `B` too (`mappedBy` is there so that you don't have to the latter).

If you only have a uni-directional mapping from `A` towards `B` you can only fetch an A entity by its id and find all B entities that are associated with it, like this (just what you've described):

```java
TypedQuery<A> tq = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM A a WHERE id = :id", A.class);
tq.setParameter("id", 100);
for (A a : tq.getResultList())
  for (B b : a.bs)
    System.out.println(b);
```

This works for me without specifying `fetch = Fetch.EAGER` and prints the same stuff as before.

Beware that if `Fetch.LAZY` is in effect you'll receive errors if you try accessing lazily loaded entities after closing an `EntityManager` or (Hibernate) `Session`. You can't do anything about this: this is the way it's supposed to work.

```
EntityManager em = ...
// fetch your B instances
List<B> bs = ...
em.close();
for (B b : bs)
  for (A a : b.as)
    // *BOOM*
    System.out.println(a);
```

You can do two things to prevent *BOOM* from happening.

1. Close your `EntityManager` or `Session` *after* you're done with your `A` objects and don't use them anymore. If you call `b.as` before `em` gets closed Hibernate (or any other persistence provider) will load `A` objects lazily from the database.
2. On your `B` entity's `@ManyToMany` annotation change `fetch` to `FetchType.EAGER`. This way, when you fetch `B` objects from the database their `Set<A> as` property will be loaded by Hiberate too (further control can be practiced with different `CascadeType` settings—I think).

I propose that you use a bi-directional mapping instead (don't omit `mappedBy`) or make `B` the owning side (but the former would be much useful).

### Tables

#### *test.a*

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |
| data  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
```

#### *test.b*

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |
| data  | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
```

#### *test.a_has_b*

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| a_id  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| b_id  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

### Data

#### *test.a*

```
+-----+------+
| id  | data |
+-----+------+
| 100 | a    |
| 200 | aa   |
| 300 | aaa  |
+-----+------+
```

#### *test.b*

```
+-----+------+
| id  | data |
+-----+------+
| 333 | b    |
| 666 | bb   |
| 999 | bbb  |
+-----+------+
```

#### *test.a_has_b*

```
+------+------+
| a_id | b_id |
+------+------+
|  100 |  333 |
|  300 |  333 |
|  100 |  999 |
+------+------+
```

### Entities

#### *A*

```java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "test", name = "a")
public final class A {

  @Id
  public int id;

  @Basic
  public String data;

  @ManyToMany(targetEntity = B.class,
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(schema = "test",
             name = "a_has_b",
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(table = "a",
                                       name = "a_id",
                                       referencedColumnName = "id"),
             inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(table = "b",
                                              name = "b_id",
                                              referencedColumnName = "id"))
  public Set<B> bs = Sets.newLinkedHashSet();

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "A{id=" + id + ", data=" + data + "}";
  }
}
```

#### *B*

```java
@Entity
@Table(schema = "test", name = "b")
public final class B {

  @Id
  public int id;

  @Basic
  public String data;

  // omitting mappedBy results in a uni-directional relationship
  @ManyToMany(targetEntity = A.class,
              cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
              fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
              mappedBy = "bs")
  public Set<A> as = Sets.newLinkedHashSet();

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "B{id=" + id + ", data=" + data + "}";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kohanyi, Thanks for your answer. So that means I have no way to use JPA QL to query the non-owning side without specifying a property set in the owning side.

Comment: If Iam not wrong, specifying fetch=fetch.LAZY will give me the exception Session closed when I access the data. Let me check again and let you know.

Comment: Hi there, if not fetch.EAGER, I will have this error: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: A.bs, no session or session was closed

Comment: @KhueVu I've updated my answer (the middle part) regarding the error you get. If you have to access lazily loaded state after your session is closed: load the state eagerly instead or don't close the session until you're done manipulating, reading the state.

Comment: @KhueVu Just a single more thing that I really want to pin point for you: I'm Hungarian and in Hungary eastern name order is used (just as in Singapore—your home country) and such, you can call me Robert, that's my given name. I really wanted to say this, because English people (people from countries using western name order) _always_ call me Kohányi, which is irritating. That's the way it should work. When a person (with a western ordered name) comes to Hungary he/she _always_ addressed or referred to by his/her western ordered name. (No offense meant—really, not a single bit!)

Comment: @Robert: Hi thanks, for your help. I guess the solution should be to use Eager fetching. As I have a separate service layer annotated with Spring Transactional to get the object, so I don't control the transaction at the caller code. And no problem, I will call you Robert.